# PHP is not sending any Parameters via POST/CURL after upgrading backend server (frontend server no change)

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04

I have upgraded the backend server to PHP7 /Ubunutu 18. There is a form_process.php which is accessed via CUR/PHP from another server (still PHP5.3). On the old testsystem the code is still running but on the new instance there are no parameters set.

How can I find the rootcause, might it be that I have to change something in `.htaccess`? This is the response it get:

```
name=XXX.de&email=versuch5%40XXX.de&stadt=60&stadtteile=6018&zimmerpreismin=600&zimmerpreismax=1200&zimmeranzahl=3&http://mywebsite.net/PROD/backend/form_process.phpCURL_RESULT: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2019 10:35:42 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

```
Die Variable POST ist gesetzt: 1<BR>Globals:array(14) {
  ["_GET"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_POST"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_COOKIE"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_FILES"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_REQUEST"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["GLOBALS"]=>
  array(14) {
    ["_GET"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_POST"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_COOKIE"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_FILES"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_REQUEST"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["GLOBALS"]=>
    *RECURSION*
    ["vorname"]=>
    NULL
    ["nachname"]=>
    NULL
    ["email"]=>
    NULL
    ["stadt"]=>
    NULL
    ["stadtteile"]=>
    NULL
    ["zimmerpreismin"]=>
    NULL
    ["zimmerpreismax"]=>
    NULL
    ["zimmeranzahl"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["vorname"]=>
  NULL
  ["nachname"]=>
  NULL
  ["email"]=>
  NULL
  ["stadt"]=>
  NULL
  ["stadtteile"]=>
  NULL
  ["zimmerpreismin"]=>
  NULL
  ["zimmerpreismax"]=>
  NULL
  ["zimmeranzahl"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: `form.php` or `form_process.php`, which one is it?

Comment: Hi @04FS, it is form_process.php. I corrected it also in the text above.

Comment: Could be an (accidental) redirect maybe. Modify your cURL command to not automatically follow those, and see what response you get then. (Or verify from the other end, via the server access log, if you have access.)

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment - but it's a bit long....

> on the new instance there are no parameters set

So the host *sending* the data has not changed, but the host *receiving* the data has changed? Then the title of your question is wrong.

You might want to spend some time finding out what a [MCV example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and creating one both for testing and for questions here. It is very hard to fix errors in code/config when we don't get to see the code/config. You should also be including details of how your PHP is connected to the webserver

Comment: This is the problem. I do not were to start. access.log error_log  have not really suspicious entries. I guess it is an configuration issue. If i remember correctly i was playing around with .htaccess a few years ago. However i did not found any on the old productionserver or current testserver. I simply seems like that the Post variables are not received. When i directly access the file with an browser the GET parameters are printed by the code. But this is GET not POST via CURL.